# Stored procedure input as partition name not working in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, partitioning, database-partitioning

This is my stored procedure and input is the partition name to be exchanged. However, the query cannot recognize my input name ('DATA_EXCHANGE_PAYLOAD_20160630') but this partition did exist in the database.

```
    CREATE
        OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exchange_partitions (partition_name IN VARCHAR2) AS

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    '

    ALTER TABLE BUCLM_ADAPTERDB.DATA_EXCHANGE_PAYLOAD EXCHANGE PARTITION partition_name
        WITH TABLE BUCLM_ADAPTERDB.DATA_EXCHANGE_PAYLOAD_TEMP
    ';
    END;

    exec exchange_partitions('DATA_EXCHANGE_PAYLOAD_20160630');
```

Comment: That's because you're not actually using the `partition_name` parameter at all.  It's looking for a string called `partition_name`. Look closely and you'll see it.

Comment: how can I modify it? I am new to oracle database and I google and cannot find the result. @sstan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `partition_name` parameter is not being used.  The `alter table` statement is literally looking for the string `partition_name`. This is not what you want.

To fix it, concatenate the value of `partition_name` into the dynamic SQL using the concatenation operator `||`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exchange_partitions (partition_name IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE BUCLM_ADAPTERDB.DATA_EXCHANGE_PAYLOAD
                       EXCHANGE PARTITION ' || partition_name || ' WITH
                       TABLE BUCLM_ADAPTERDB.DATA_EXCHANGE_PAYLOAD_TEMP';
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'ALTER TABLE BUCLM_ADAPTERDB.DATA_EXCHANGE_PAYLOAD 
                    EXCHANGE PARTITION :1  WITH TABLE 
                    BUCLM_ADAPTERDB.DATA_EXCHANGE_PAYLOAD_TEMP'
                    USING partition_name;
```